# is there any way to inject an association on the fly for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So for instance I have a Guest model,

While i'm using the Guest model on some action, id like to inject this association (only on that action)

belongs_to :category

How do i do that?

Comment: Why not just define it properly in the model? What's the benefit in doing it on the fly other than just making the code hard to maintain? For that association to work, you'd need a key in the guest table to reference the category, so it'd be relatively static anyway. You probably could get it to work using `class_eval`, but that's incredibly dirty and will only trip you up later. Just set it up in the model and only use it when you need it.

Comment: Why would you do that?  Having it accessible for setting and viewing only in one action might make sense, but associations need to be consistent in the model.

Comment: Please explain into more detail what you are trying to accomplish, why you think it should be dynamic.

Comment: hey all - thanks for trying to help. Its for some legacy code that is already deprecated. I need the data from it that's why i only need it in one part - in the migration scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with @Beerlington that you might be trying to be too clever, here's the answer:

1. Make a module like so:

   ```
   module Categorical
       def self.included(included_class)
         included_class.instance_eval do
             # from here to the end of this block, imagine that you are in the class
             # source itself. Add associations or instance methods, for example

             belongs_to :category
         end
       end
   end
   ```
2. Now, include that module in your class:

   ```
   class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
       include Categorical
       ....

   end
   ```

And there you have it!

This could be useful if you are also adding named_scopes to your Categorical class, or other helper methods...

Comment: thanks i really haven't tried it yet but it looks like this is what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be trying to get a little clever with your code. While it may be possible to do, it's not a native feature and would likely introduce a lot of hacky metaprogramming, and therefore some potentially nasty bugs. I would recommend taking a step back and seeing if you can rethink the problem you're trying to solve. Are you using RESTful controllers? It's hard to say based on your question, but usually the answer is no when you start asking questions like this. Does your controller have too much logic? Maybe some of what you're trying to do can be moved to models. If you provide more information about what you're doing, you'll probably get more useful responses.

Comment: yeah sure is trying to be clever. need it for a legacy/deprecated code i don't want to put in the model, i just need it in one part of the code, in a migration script.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically maybe it's possible but in your case it can't be accomplish.
Because `belongs_to` is a database issue, it means one of the database table has id to another table. ActiveRecord just wraps around all these functionality and then it looks like you're interacting with Ruby objects. So you can't temporarily change your database and then change back on the fly for reasonable price.